# Should I separate a portion of my 401k into an annuity?

Tags: united-states, 401k, annuity

Bank financial planner thinks I have too much (dollar wise) in mutual funds in my 401k.

I am 12 years from retirement.

They suggest taking a portion of that and opening an annuity for some protection of money.

> I would have 3 indices to choose from.  3 switchable performance
> levels to choose from yearly.  Most with a -10% loss safety net and
> 10% cap.  Fee=1.75% annually.

Looks like in my state, annuities fall under the division of insurance.

Sounds too good to be true to a financial illiterate like myself.

**Are annuities marketing scams or a legitimate way to diversify and protect my income?**

Comment: Can you advise? How will they credit the acct based on the index? Just the index, or including dividends? Any details will help you get a better answer.

Comment: `Fee=1.75% annually` is pretty high.

Comment: Does your 401(k) have funds besides stock mutual funds? Are you even able to pull money from your 401(k) while you are still employed by that company?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is actually an IRA or some other retirement account vs. a 401k.

Comment: I also considered a "loss and gain capped annuity" but decided against it, instead choosing "defensive" mutual funds.

Comment: Is this your current employer (if so, I'm dubious that you can get the money out; if a former employer, then *roll it over* into an *IRA* at a brokerage like (alphabetically) Fidelity, Schwab or Vanguard.  I'm staring at retirement, and "sleeping well" is more important than high yields;  thus, I've invested in "defensive" funds, which *historically* have fallen less than the market, and recovered quicker.

Answer (score 2):

### Because it's being sold *to you*, it's scam-ish

The industry norm is "financial advisors" who dispense free advice, but are paid very hefty sales commissions when they place you in certain financial products.

The reason you are being sold this annuity right now is it recently became legal to sell annuities inside IRAs.  The "advisor" HAHA salesman actually, is driving the transaction, to collect a commission not because it's the right thing for your investment.

Indeed, annuities like many financial peoducts are complex on purpose, *specifically so you cannot understand them*.  They know people tend to "go tilt" and search for someone to trust, and there is this "financial advisor" ready to "help" them.  They create the problem and the solution.

### All this puts the cart before the horse.

Trying to include financial products in your portfolio,  *reactively*, because some law changed or some salesman called, is an extremely poor design approach.

What you really need is a holistic (whole), top-down review of your retirement planning, from someone who is **actually on your side**.

The place to get that is from a *real* financial advisor.  Someone who does not feed their family with sales commissions on high-fee financial products they sell.  Someone who actually lives on the flat-rate or hourly commission, **and only does business that way**.

*Not like my financial advisor, who opened with several load funds and annuities.  I said "No no, I am looking for a fee-based advisor."  The response: **"OK, give me $3000!"***.

That guy would just recommend you into the exact same annuities and load funds, because that's the mentality of such people: they *actually believe* the things with the highest sales commissions are coincidentally the best things for you!  The *conflict of interest* is an elephant in the room so big they can't even see it.

The right person is a *fee only* advisor who never takes a sales commission on any product, and does not work for a company which offers investment products.

Answer (score 1):

> Are annuities marketing scams or a legitimate way to diversify and protect my income?

In general annuities are legitimate financial instruments that make sense for some people at certain times.  They are not right for everyone.  There are also scammers and other disreputable people who are looking to swindle you out of your hard-earned money.

If your financial advisor, who I assume is someone you trust and is hopefully a licensed professional, is advising you to purchase some annuities, presumably they also have some specific ones in mind.  You should carefully research them and make your own decision.

Again, for SOME people and some times annuities make sense.  I don't think anyone here is able to understand your situation well enough to say yes or no to them for you.

> Looks like in my state, annuities fall under the division of insurance.

In most places annuities are highly regulated since the seller is guaranteeing a particular return for the term of the instrument, most often your life.  So actuarials come into play as well as regulations on how they invest the funds so that they don't run out of money to pay you before you die.

Answer (score 1):

The more complicated the annuity (switchable, safety net, capped returns), the harder it is to see if it is worth it.

The disclosed fee is 1.75%, but are there other potential fees such as exit penalty, fund fees, etc.?

Schwab has a [calculator](https://www.schwab.com/annuities/fixed-income-annuity-calculator) for simpler annuities. Put some numbers in to make some comparisons with what you are being offered at the bank.

Answer (score 1):

There is a line - “annuities are sold, not bought”. In other words, no one actually seeks them out.

To be fair, there are many flavors of annuity. One is called an immediate annuity. This will pay me a return of interest plus a bit of my principal. So, at 65, I might get 6%, but I have given up the deposit. I die, 5, 10 years in, and there’s no inheritance for the kids.

Then there are indexed annuities that offer some return indexed to some stock market return. Funny, your return is capped, in return for a minimum return (i.e. a maximum loss of 10%). So. Take a market that returns 10% on average, with an 18% standard deviation. Cap each years return at 10%, but cap losses at 10%. Use the index with no dividends, about a 2% haircut, along with near 2% fee. 4% total annual cost along with a questionable way of crediting gains. That sounds like “not something I’d let anyone I cared for invest in”. But short of criminal. I just don’t know why.

I once sifted through the details of a particular equity indexed annuity to help someone. The salesman said it offered a maximum potential return of 24%/yr. I tried to find 'past performance' examples, and there were none. For this EIA, each month was capped at 2%, but losses were capped at 2% as well. And of course dividends were ignored. I applied this formula to the 80's and 90's market data, 2 decades that gave a CAGR of 17.99% on the S&P. The result was less than 6%/yr, less than one would have gotten in CDs or government paper (bills, bonds, notes). Consider a year of 6 random months with -2%, and 6 with +4%.  This should total about 12% (12.087% in reality), plus about 2% in dividends. The crediting capped the 4% months to 2%, and the full year to zero.

To the annuity defenders, this is my experience with a particular kind of annuity. I have far less of an issue with the immediate annuity that is straightforward to explain, and understand.

Comment: Re "there’s no inheritance for the kids", that may actually be a plus. Kids know they will have to support themselves, won't squabble over the inheritance after you die, won't be tempted to knock you off 'cause they're tired of waiting for that inheritance...

Comment: It’s a feature I suppose, if one wants it. It also might let the old person become a financial burden on the kids. It has its place in PF.